# Tips to debug serial COM sensor data on VB (exe)

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I have a chinese charge controller reporting data to a windows software via a serial cable.

I have managed to sniff the COM port and successfully isolated the data being sent by the software to request the controller to transmit sensor data.

The data being returned by the controller is a single line:

(for example)

```
..p...............!............ª.x
```

Somehow the damn thing is updating at least 4 numerical values in the software with that single line. Each second a line like that is returned, but I'm very confused because the data shown in the app is sometimes the same but the serial data received to represent such data is different. As if it was encrypted somehow (which is stupid).

Here is an example of 10 different lines being reported back from the controller. These are received one each second.

```
..p€...........................ª.Ï
..p...................!........ª.w
..p€...........................ª.Ï
..p............................ª.O
..p............................ª.Q
..p............................ª.P
```

Funny thing is each one of those 6 lines is representing EXACTLY the same data values on the receiving software (measuring voltage and amps).

The windows software is a very crappy VB.6 exe which i was able to decompile, but it seems to rely heavy on p-code, PCOMM.DLL, MXTOOL and other crap.

To anybody with serial expertise:

- is this controller encrypting its sensor data?
- if so, what technique should i use to figure out how it is encrypting its 4 values?
- Finally, do you suggest any serial apps or decompilers that will aid in this?

Pedro

Comment: It's just binary data.  Whatever you are using to show you these lines are replacing characters with `.`.  I bet those are `NUL` bytes.  You said you already know how to sniff the data and see the data in the application that works, so now you simply need to watch that data and the results and figure out how it works.  There is no magic, just some work to figure it out the patterns.  Start by watching numbers increment/deincrement and see what endian they are using.

Comment: Thanks Brad.

This is how the hex response looks like:

EB 90 EB 90 00 06 00 20 00 0C 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA 01 5A

Comment: Edit your question.  Don't paste it in a comment box.  And, that isn't helpful to us because we don't know what the data correlates to.  This is something you will have to experiment with to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct baudrate to read in the data?

Are you using the correct parity and data bits and stop bits ?

Do you have any documentation of the device?

Do you know what the data should look like?
Does the data consist of normal ascii characters or is it some chinese script?